# Indices of Coxeter groups in themselves

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups

Every Euclidean Coxeter group ($P_n$, $Q_n$, $R_n$, $S_n$, $T_7$, $T_8$, $T_9$, $U_5$, $V_3$, $W_2$) contains infinitely many scaled copies of itself as subgroups. What are all the possible indices of these subgroups for each?